# Cambie UIWebView a WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Estoy realizando una app IOS soy nuevo en swift en la aplicación contenía un componente UIWebView y el html que es el contenido se veía bien el tamaño al correr la aplicación y asi se veía pero tuve que cambiarlo a WKWebView y sale bien pequeño todo el Html

Este es con UIWebView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es con WKWebView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puedo hacer ahi y porque es más pequeño el texto en WKWebView y en UIWebView el texto es normal?

El twiiter me sale bien pequeño en WkWebView.

Realice otro ejemplo con el WKWebView y UIWebView y necesito que este el WKWebView como el UIWebView con el tamaño del twitter por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Adrian. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de cómo llamas a la `url` en los dos casos? Salvo que cargues un archivo `html` propio y no te reconozca las hojas de estilo `css`. Agrega lo que mas puedas para poder ayudarte.